# How do I include the submitters email in a PHP form?

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I am using a simple HTML form for an event registration and I would like to send a PHP confirmation email to the registrant with the same information that is going to the administrator.

Here are the details:

```
$emailFromName = $_POST['name'];
$emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$emailFromPhone = $_POST['phone'];
```

I would like to use the value from **$emailFrom** in the following email address to:

```
$emailTo = "name@domain.com", \"$emailFrom\";
```

edit: Added new configuration:

```
$emailHeaders = 'From: "Conference" <noreply@conference.org>' . 'CC: . $emailFrom .';
```

This obviously doesn't work, but you get the idea of what I am trying to.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want `$emailTo` to read if `$emailFrom` is `me@myplace.com`? There are a few things wrong with the line `$emailTo = "name@domain.com", \"$emailFrom\";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add headers to the `mail` function...

for example:

```
$headers = 'From: Family History Conference <noreply@familyhistoryconference.org>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: noreply@familyhistoryconference.org' . "\r\n" .
    'CC: ' . $emailFrom . "\r\n";
```

and then

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

### References:

- [PHP Mail Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Would this be correct? $emailHeaders = 'From: "Family History Conference" <noreply@familyhistoryconference.org>';
            $emailHeaders = 'Cc: ' . $emailFrom . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

You put `"From: $name <$emailFrom>"` in the additional parameters of the `mail()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you want to CC a copy of the message to the user as well as the administrator?

It depends on which PHP library you're using to send it. If you're using the default PHP mail() function, you'll need to add additional headers:

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . $emailFrom . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail('admin@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Like this?  $emailTo = "admin@mail.com";
        $subject = "Conference Registration";
        $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $emailFrom . "\r\n";

Comment: Hi Jack. Please take a look at the edited code at the top. Is that correct for adding cc to the header info? Thanks.